# Unintentional deleting reference to an object on useEffect in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, cytoscape.js, react-state-management

I am new to ReactJs, but I need to maintain some preexisting codebase. There is one behavior that I can't understand (and get around it).

I have a `Store` object that holds data that needs to be rendered with the `Cytoscape` library.

Currently, I have `useEffect` trigger on the `Store` object that creates data for Cy lib and populates the library. Now I would like to skip some updates when they are not necessary. Something like this (it is pseudocode):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(store.dontNeedRerender) {
    console.log("Skip this rendering");
  } else {
    const elements = convertDataToCyData();
    const cy: cytoscape.Core = cytoscape({
        container: document.getElementById("cytoscape-dataset-panel"),
        // @ts-ignore
        elements,

        // @ts-ignore
        style: style,
        ...store.config,
      });
    graphInit(cy);
    setCy(cy);
  }
}, [store]);
```

My problem is, that every time the `useEffect()` is called `cy` is emptied (library rendered empty screen), and then repopulate. But if store.dontNeedRerender is true, the screen remains empty (instead of just skipping rerendering...)

I guess this is something to do with state management... but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
// useEffect with empty dependency
useEffect(() => {
  // some function
  console.log("I am rendered");
  // this only trigger once on first render
}, []);

// useEffect with 'one' dependency
useEffect(() => {
  // some function
  console.log("I am rendered");
  // this only trigger twice on first render
  // then render everytime variable 'one' change
}, [one]);

// useEffect with dependency which is a boolean
useEffect(() => {
  // this will rerender when condition change
  obj.someCondition ? console.log(obj.name) : undefined;
  // adding the whole object 'obj' as dependency is not necessary
  // if obj.name will be the same in every re-render, 
  // don't add it to dependency
}, [obj.someCondition]);
```

Comment: Hi @Four, thanks for the reply. I actually know this... my question is, why on the second one (with 'one' dependency) object that was built with one is cleared even if useEffect is empty.

Comment: I do not fully understand your comment. Made some edit, based on I understood your comment.